# How to use php values in js

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php 
    $query1="SELECT * FROM user_photos_offline WHERE ssmid='11'";
    $sql=mysql_query($query1);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
       $result=$row['name'].',';//resuts kani,raja,mahi,gobi
    }
?>
<script>
    var photos='<?php echo $result;?>';
</script>
```

I am getting only last value (gobi) but i want all values in js. i dont know how to get the all values in javascript

Answer (score 2):

you have to add your results in an array:

```
 $results=array();
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
     $results[]=$row['name'];//fill your array
 }
```

//then implode your array

```
<script>
    var photos='<?php echo implode(",",$results); ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Now i am getting              Array

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "overwriting" $result again and again within the while-loop make it an array and append the items.
Then when outputting the variable use [json_encode()](http://docs.php.net/json_encode) to get a valid javascript object/array notation.

```
$result=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    // append the value of the field 'name' of the current record to $result
    $result[]=$row['name'].',';//resuts kani,raja,mahi,gobi
}
...
var photos=<?php echo json_encode($result);?>
```

The [mysql_* extension is deprecated](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) and will be removed with php 7. Better pick [another api](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) like mysqli or PDO_mysql.

Comment: Thank My dear friend VolkerK ,now i am getting correct answer